# Assignment to a List Container Confusion

Tags: raku

I may be suffering from brain fade, but according to the docs regarding Items and List assignment (https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#Item_and_list_assignment ),

**Assignment to a List container (list-context) always triggers list assignment.**

However that seems to conflict with what I get from the code (here reproduced in the raku repl)..

```
> my %syns-by-name = %(Bq => ["Bq", "becquerel", "becquerels"], C => ["C", "coulomb", "coulombs"],)
    {Bq => [Bq becquerel becquerels], C => [C coulomb coulombs]}
> my Str @res = %syns-by-name{'Bq'};
    Type check failed in assignment to @res; expected Str but got Array (["Bq", "becquerel", ...) in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
> my Str @res = [|%syns-by-name{'Bq'}];
    [Bq becquerel becquerels]
```

Is this a bug, or do I misunderstand what the intent is...?

```
Welcome to ™ v2020.10.
Implementing the ™ programming language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2020.10.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR** If a non-native item is mutable via assignment, it's a `Scalar`. List assignment does not flatten `Scalar` items. <sup>**[1]**</sup>

## An inkling

Consider this code:

```
my %map = :a;
%map<a> = 42;
say %map<a>; # 42
```

The assignment works because:

```
say %map<a>.VAR.WHAT; # (Scalar)
```

## "list assignment"

Consider this code:

```
my $scalar = 1,2;       # Useless use of constant integer 2
say $scalar;            # 1

my @list1 = 1,2;        # "list assignment", so RHS is iterated
say @list1;             # [1 2]
```

So that's one difference between item and list assignment.

```
my @list3 = [1,2];      # Again, RHS is iterated
say @list3;             # [1 2]

my @list2 = (1,2);      # Again, RHS is iterated
say @list2;             # [1 2]

my @list4 = 1,(2,3);    # Again, RHS is iterated. Second element stays as a `List`.
say @list4;             # [1 (2 3)]

my @list5 = 1,[2,3];    # Again, RHS is iterated. Second element stays as an `Array`.
say @list5;             # [1 [2 3]]
```

If there's just one item listed on the RHS, *and it isn't a `Scalar`*, list assignment flattens it. But in all other scenarios list assignment doesn't flatten items.

```
my @list6 = $[1,2];     # RHS is a `Scalar`. So it doesn't get flattened.
say @list6;             # [[1 2]]
```

## I'm sooo confused!

Golfing the situation in the Q:

```
my Str @res = %( :a[42,99] )<a>;
```

This yields the same kind of error.

Because:

```
say .VAR.WHAT given :a[42,99]<a>;       # (Array)
say .VAR.WHAT given (% = :a[42,99])<a>; # (Scalar)
```

## Footnotes

<sup>**[1]**</sup> When surmise yields surprise, and you turn that into learning, you realize and idealize your investment in [ERN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error-related_negativity)ing.

Comment: "(i) an `Array` stored as a `Hash` value is contained in a `Scalar`" *Any* value stored as a `Hash` value is, *by default*, stored in a `Scalar`. The same is even true with so-called immutable `Map`s. (But, I presume, won't be at all, by default or otherwise, with the upcoming fully immutable `Dict`s.) But any value can be *bound* to eliminate the `Scalar`, eg `say .VAR.WHAT given (% := :a[42,99])<a>; # (Array)`.

Comment: So, to test my understanding, in raku, when one has an Array as a Hash value, it's presented back as a Scalar on access?

Comment: "(ii) you need to double decant it if you want List assignment." (I'd advise sticking to lowercase "list", not "List" because it isn't to do with the `List` type, but just lists in the most generic sense, and "list assignment" in particular.) One never needs multiple deconts (eg postfix `<>`s )in any Raku code because there can never be a `Scalar` inside a `Scalar`. So, if you ever need a decont , one decont is always enough.

Comment: Oops - deleted my first replies - apologies. It's clear to me - appreciate the guidance!! Feel free to delete / alter you replies to my replies - I'll back off until tomorrow.

Comment: "So, to test my understanding, in raku, when one has an Array as a Hash value, it's presented back as a Scalar on access" If there's no `Scalar` (eg as shown at the end of my comment about "(i) ..."), then it's an `Array`, pure and simple. There's no `Scalar` containing the `Array`. But if an `Array` (or any other value) *is* held in a `Scalar` (which you can check by calling `.VAR.WHAT` on it), then features that check the object's `VAR.WHAT` (I think it's just flattening?) will spot that it's a `Scalar` and deal accordingly. For other features the `Scalar` will yield the value it contains.

Comment: @p6steve I'll sleep on it but I think I'll probably integrate the additional learning that's happening for both of us due to our exchange, here in comments, into the answer, and then delete my comments. I'm prolly gonna remove ERN from footnote too, because it's just whimsy, and is a poor fit for what I really want to convey, because ERN is really about motor response in combination with mental activity, which doesn't apply here, whereas the thing I want to emphasize is the surmise => surprise combo (cf DWIM/WAT), which I have taught myself to always enjoy and turn into a learning opportunity.

Comment: Hi @raiph - that's all cool - I have learned quite a bit more, appreciate the dialog!!

Answer (score 2):

*Note*: You can't go wrong by reading [`@raiph`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65457733/891440). However, I'll try to explain what is going on here and propose possible solutions.

In Raku, [context](https://docs.raku.org/language/contexts) is everything. Meaning that different contexts are triggered in different, well, contexts, implying different *boxing* or *unboxing* features of the data structure you're working with.

Let's look at this

```
my %syns-by-name = %(Bq => ["Bq", "becquerel", "becquerels"], C => ["C", "coulomb", "coulombs"],)
```

We do know we are in an "Associative" context because of the percentage marks both sides of the equal sign. We wouldn't even need it on the right hand side:

```
my %syns-by-name = Bq => ["Bq", "becquerel", "becquerels"], C => ["C", "coulomb", "coulombs"]
```

because, looking at the lhs, it's still a Associative, so we know what we have in our hands. Self same rhs code in this cotext:

```
my @list-of-signs = Bq => ["Bq", "becquerel", "becquerels"], C => ["C", "coulomb", "coulombs"] # [Bq => [Bq becquerel becquerels] C => [C coulomb coulombs]]
```

Will yield a list of pairs. So we check that what you mentioned in your OP:

> Assignment to a List container (list-context) always triggers list assignment.

is tru-ish. This is a "list" container, we turn the rhs into a list just by context. There's no ambiguity of what's going on here: the rhs is a comma-separated list, the lhs is a Positional. So here you go.

The situation is slightly different in your code. It's maybe clarified a bit more if we use 2020.12

```
 my %syns-by-name = Bq => ["Bq", "becquerel", "becquerels"], C => ["C", "coulomb", "coulombs"]
my Str @res = %syns-by-name{'Bq'};
# Type check failed in assignment; expected Positional[Str] but got Array ($["Bq", "becquerel", ...)
```

Might not see the difference at first sight, so I'll highlight it here:

> Type check failed in binding; expected Positional[Str] but got Array (**$**["Bq", "becquerel", ...)

That shows that the array is [*itemized*](https://docs.raku.org/language/contexts#Item_context), it's been *boxed* so that it can fit into a scalar-like thing like the value of a hash key. By default, Hash values are Scalar, with this composed into their definition:

```
role Associative[::TValue = Mu, ::TKey = Str(Any)] { }
```

So still what you mention holds: list assignment is triggered, as in "list context". However, the single item can be converted into a list only in a way: by making it the single element in a list. If you look at the error report closely, it's what it's saying: hey, you told me that you were gonna give me a list of Strs. This is not that! It's a list of (itemized) Arrays! This works:

```
my List @res = %syns-by-name{'Bq'};
# [(Bq becquerel becquerels)]
```

What we need to do is to «unbox» this thing, that is, to retrieve the Array that inhabits the Scalar. Easy-peasy:

```
my Str @res = %syns-by-name{'Bq'}<>;
# [Bq becquerel becquerels]
```

The [de-cont operator (which maybe should be called "unbox" or "de-Scalarize" or "de-itemize" operator)](https://docs.raku.org/language/containers) does the right thing for you. That's probably not what you want, however. You want your arrays to be arrays. That' however, has proved a bit more tricky and I am going to need another SO question to solve it.

Comment: Thank you @JJ - I much appreciate the explanation. It’s a good, consistent design to have the value of a Hash always be a Scalar. Just need to be aware that the Array will be assigned as one item, unless you want to flatten (|) or unbox (<>).