# How can you assign values to a Hash key without concomitant boxing (i.e. itemization)?

Tags: syntax, raku

Coming from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456629/assignment-to-a-list-container-confusion), I'm trying to have a `List` (or non-scalar thing, in general) as the value assigned to a Hash key, this way:

```
my %syns-by-name does Associative[Str,List] = Bq => ("Bq", "becquerel", "becquerels");
my Str  @syns = %syns-by-name<Bq>;
```

That does not work, however. Lists are itemized before being assigned, so the value is always a Scalar. You need to do a workaround to actually make this work:

```
my %syns-by-name does Associative[Str,List] = Bq => ("Bq", "becquerel", "becquerels");

my @list := <C coulomb coulombs>;
%syns-by-name<C> := @list;

my Str  @syns = %syns-by-name<C>;
say @syns;
```

This returns what we were looking for, a list. However, how could we do that directly on the assignment and convince a list is a list and not an itemized list?

Comment: Hi @jjmerelo does `my Str  @syns2 = @(%syns-by-name<Bq>);` give you what you want?

Comment: @jubilatious1 it might, but I was looking more for ways to _define_ the variable, more than access its values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you don't need mutation afterwards, use a `Map` instead of a `Hash`.

```
my %syns-by-name is Map = Bq => ("Bq", "becquerel", "becquerels");
my Str @syns = %syns-by-name<Bq>;
say @syns; # [Bq becquerel becquerels]
```

Since there's no expectation that entries in a `Map` are assignable, it doesn't create `Scalar` containers for the values.

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
role deconting {
    method AT-KEY(\key) {
        callsame<>
    }
}
my %h does deconting = a => <a b c>;
dd $_ for %h<a>;  # "a"␤"b"␤"c"␤
```

This makes sure that the hash that does the "deconting" role will always return whatever is in the hash decontainerized.

Making it decontainerized on assignment can also be done, but is a lot more tricky as that would need tweaking of at least two methods: `STORE` and `ASSIGN-KEY`.

Answer (score 4):

Despite the excellent answers from @Jonathan_Worthington and @Elizabeth_Mattijsen, I wanted to post the code below, which utilizes simple decontainerization:

```raku
~$ raku
Welcome to ™ v2020.10.
Implementing the ™ programming language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2020.10.

To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> my %syns-by-name =  Bq => ("Bq", "becquerel", "becquerels");
{Bq => (Bq becquerel becquerels)}
> my Str  @syns = %syns-by-name<Bq>;
Type check failed in assignment to @syns; expected Str but got List (("Bq", "becquerel", ...)
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1

> my Str  @syns = %syns-by-name<Bq>[];
[Bq becquerel becquerels]
>
```

I gather there is an academic question here as to how the variable is *defined* versus how the values of the variable are *accessed*. However I don't want a casual reader to conclude that Raku is lacking functionality vis-à-vis hashes and lists.

```raku
> my %syns-by-name  = Bq => ("Bq", "becquerel", "becquerels");
{Bq => (Bq becquerel becquerels)}
> dd $_ for %syns-by-name<Bq>[]
"Bq"
"becquerel"
"becquerels"
Nil
> my $list = <C coulomb coulombs>;
(C coulomb coulombs)
> say $list.WHAT
(List)
> %syns-by-name<C> = $list
(C coulomb coulombs)
> dd $_ for %syns-by-name<C>[]
"C"
"coulomb"
"coulombs"
Nil
>
```

I hope this answer isn't superfluous and casual readers will benefit. Thank you.