# Why is it that sometimes we have to use coercion to access individual elements of an array?

Tags: raku

My understanding is that in the code below I wouldn't have to use (2), just (1) would suffice to print each element of the array in its own line.

```
$ cat test-hash.raku                            
use v6;                                         
                                            
my %h;                                          
                                            
say "";                                         
say "inserts a scalar";                         
%h.push: (aaa => "aaa");                        
%h.say;                                         
                                            
say "";                                         
say "turns the scalar into an array";           
%h.push: (aaa => "AAA");                        
%h.say;                                         
                                            
say "";                                         
say "(1) shows all elements of the array in a line";
.say for %h{"aaa"};                             
                                            
say "";                                         
say "(2) shows each element of the array in a line";
.say for %h{"aaa"}.Array;                       
                                            
$ raku test-hash.raku                           
                                            
inserts a scalar                                
{aaa => aaa}                                    
                                            
turns the scalar into an array                  
{aaa => [aaa AAA]}                              
                                            
(1) shows all elements of the array in a line       
[aaa AAA]                                       
                                            
(2) shows each element of the array in a line       
aaa                                             
AAA                                             
                                            
$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could argue that this is a bug in the implementation of `Array.push`, because it **assigns** an Array to the Hash element, rather than *binding* to it.  Because it assigns, the Array lives in a Scalar container, and is effectively itemized.  And being itemized, it won't be iterated over.

So, the easiest solution is to de-itemize the Hash elements before iterating:

```
.say for %h{"aaa"}<>;
```

See [decontainerization operator](https://docs.raku.org/routine/%3C%3E) for more info.

Comment: thanks, it worked ... but (for me) it's non intuitive ... in fact I think I prefer the coercion to Array

Comment: Sure!  But if that becomes very hot code for you, the `<>` will be *much* more efficient.

Comment: "in fact I think I prefer the coercion to Array"  In the spirit of TIMTOWTDI, here are a couple of other ways you could do (basically, though with subtle differences) the same thing as `%h{"aaa"}.Array`: `@(%h{"aaa"})`, `|%h{"aaa"}`, `flat %h{"aaa"}`.

Comment: did you mean `Hash.push` instead of `Array.push`? Don't Hashes put their values in scalar containers, and that's not a bug? In fact, you have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65464929/9332187) here with a mixin for the otherwise behaviour, no?